# How do I save iBooks pdf on iPhone to computer so I can delete them from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, books

My iPhone 6s+ is running out of memory. I have so many crochet patterns on my iBooks. How do I transfer those patterns to computer so i can delete them from my iPhone? When I first bought the computer I synced my phone then started deleting them from my phone, then they started deleting from the computer.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To delete them *only* from your phone, follow [these steps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205751):

> In the upper-right corner of the iBooks window, tap Select.
>
> Scroll to find the item that you want to delete, then tap it.
>
> In the upper-left corner of the iBooks window, tap Delete.
>
> Tap **Delete This Copy**.

If you tap Delete from All Devices, it will remove it from iCloud, which will cause it to be deleted from all devices (including your computer).